# чем построчно и быстро парсить большой XML файл

Tags: python, xml

Добрый день,
Нужен совет, чем лучше парсить большой xml файл.
Задача состоит:

1. читать построчно и быстро, так в файл пишутся транзакционные данные.
2. При наступлении определенных событий писать распарсеные данные в лог файл или бд.

Comment: Насколько большой файл? возможно подойдёт [SAX](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.sax.html)

Comment: начните c [`iterparse()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279). Если возникнут проблемы, задайте более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую.